# Get and Set System.Object value using Unity SerializedProperties

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, types, properties

I want to be able to specify the type with an enum and assign the value to the object variable, but I keep getting '*NullReferenceException ..*' error message.


[image]

I have this simple class:

```
[System.Serializable()]
public class ObjectValue
{
    public enum ValueType { Null, Integar, Float, String, Boolean }
    [SerializeField, HideInInspector] private ValueType type = ValueType.Null;

    public object value = null;
}
```

And by the help of a property drawer script I want to be able to view this class on the Inspector and edit the value depending on the chosen type:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ObjectValue))]
public class ObjectValue_Drawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        return base.GetPropertyHeight(property, label) + 17;
    }
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        GUI.Box(position, GUIContent.none);
        var typeEnum = property.FindPropertyRelative("type");

        position.height = 17;
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, typeEnum);
        position.y += 17;

        var value = property.FindPropertyRelative("value");
        switch (typeEnum.enumValueIndex)
        {
            case (int)ObjectValue.ValueType.Null:
                GUI.Label(position, "Null Value Type");
                break;
            case (int)ObjectValue.ValueType.Integar:
                value.intValue = EditorGUI.IntField(position, "Value", value.intValue);
                break;
            case (int)ObjectValue.ValueType.Float:
                value.floatValue = EditorGUI.FloatField(position, "Value", value.floatValue);
                break;
            case (int)ObjectValue.ValueType.String:
                value.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(position, "Value", value.stringValue);
                break;
            case (int)ObjectValue.ValueType.Boolean:
                value.boolValue = EditorGUI.Toggle(position, "Value", value.boolValue);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @BugFinder This is *not* a duplicate.of a generic question about a null reference exception. It's a perfectly valid question in the context of Unity inspector UI, even though the context could've been clarified better in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that, as of Unity 2019.2 and the time of writing of this answer, **this is impossible directly** with objects or other types that don't register as serialisedProperties, **but can still be done with a work-around.**

Said work-around consists of (ab)using the `ISerializationCallbackReceiver` interface [and thus circumvent this issue](https://answers.unity.com/questions/610303/unity-systemobject-serialization.html) by using a malleable intermediate representation for the editor. This actually works!

On a partial tangent: if using something that *is* a serialised property, you can [use hacks to access the value directly](https://forum.unity.com/threads/get-a-general-object-value-from-serializedproperty.327098/) through the use of reflection. This is helpful in our case, should you wish to manually call the custom class's `OnBeforeSerialize` method inside the Editor, for instance.